# How to print answer of 'external' recursive function in GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, recursion, factorial

This is my 2nd recursive function ever (I hope!) only this time I need it to print out in a textField. It prints out "5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1" nothing too fancy. I have a feeling my attempt is terribly wrong since in the program its underlined a very noticeable ugly shade of red.

I'm trying to understand by researching it (not working too well) and I've yet to master the whole 'theoretical thinking' side of things, so any tips or hints would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class Main {

    public static String fact(int n) {
        if(n == 1){
            return "1";
        }
        return n + " x " + (fact(n-1)); 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(fact(5));
    }

 private void itsAButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//button on GUI

//some other code that has no significant value to question

itsATextField.setText("" + return); //only line underlined

}
```

The only thing it says when hovered over it is 'illegal start of expression'

Comment: What IDE are you using? Is the whole program underlined, or just one line? What message does it give (when you hover over the underlined text)?

Comment: If you posted something sort of complete, there is a missing closing brace at the end.

Comment: @LeeMeador Just about to say that. Other than that, the code works.

Comment: Hmm, must not have copied and pasted it all for question, but I promise it is there in the program

Comment: Tell us more about the "ugly red" stuff.

Comment: Ah, seeing your edit... that line is bad. What are you trying to achieve with that? What is `return`?

Comment: Its just the red lines that netbeans sets in if something won't work.

Comment: I am trying to get the output of "5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1" to output in itsATextField and not just "system.out.println(fact(5));"

Comment: I'm just not sure who to combine the two - being function and Tfield

Comment: wait wow I'm an idiot, I think I got this...

Comment: Well. You know the factorial function works. So change the `main()` over run the GUI. You will have a whole new set of issues.

Comment: New set of issues? All i did was change "itsATextField.setText("" + return);" to "itsATextField.setText(fact(5));" hence why I called myself an idiot since I should of gotten that...

Answer (score 1):

```
itsATextField.setText(fact(5));
```

would be syntactically correct.

However, it will not be a complete program with a GUI, of course.

Comment: Thanks, I came up with that conclusion earlier however what do you mean by "not a complete program with a GUI"?

Comment: @user2407152 The code in the original post will not show any gui, it is missing window setup, etc. For a simple example of how to setup a Java Swing Application see e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/start/HelloWorldSwingProject/src/start/HelloWorldSwing.java